# Manual of tikzmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikzmath

I am a strong user of `tikzmath` to implement several things in the numeric calculus.
However, I miss of a complete manual of `tikzmath` (separate of `tikz`), where I can to find all its features, functions, examples of implementations, etc...
Thus, if someone can share with me this document, I thank you very much.

Comment: Is this not contained in chapter **58 Math Library** of the regular [PGF manual](//texdoc.net/pkg/pgf)?

Comment: The full list of built-in functions are documented in Chapter 95 "Additional Mathematical Commands" of `pgfmanual`.